# Mapserver not displaying a raster properly

Tags: raster, openlayers, web-mapping, mapserver

I have a 32bit floating point raster containing only five values (-2, -1, 0, 1, 2 + -999000000 for noData don't ask me why, it was delivered to me), no compression, projected (EPSG:3857). I am using mapserver in combination with OpenLayers to display it in a web application as a tile layer. Everything seems ok and no errors are reported however this is what I get:

[image]

It looks like some tiles are not loaded (straight border of yellow colour in the upper middle) moreover there shouldn't be any transparent pixels over the land, water is noData. As I zoom in an d out as well as pan pixels and tiles seem to randomly appear and disappear.

Here is my basic mapfile I also tried different combinations of PROCESSING configurations but none of them work:

```
MAP
  NAME "qqqq"
  CONFIG "PROJ_LIB" "../../share/proj/"
  STATUS ON
  UNITS METERS
  WEB
    IMAGEPATH "/ms4w/tmp/ms_tmp/"
    IMAGEURL "/ms_tmp/"
    METADATA
      "wms_title"     "WMS qqqq"
      "wms_onlineresource" "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?"   ##required
      "wms_srs" "EPSG:4326 EPSG:3857"
      "wms_enable_request" "*"
      "WMS_FEATURE_INFO_MIME_TYPE" "application/json"
    END
  END

  PROJECTION
    "init=epsg:3857"
  END

  #
  # Start of layer definitions
  #

  LAYER
    NAME "products"
    PROCESSING "NODATA=-999000000"
    TEMPLATE "templates/NDVITemplateJSON.js"
    TOLERANCE 5
    TOLERANCEUNITS PIXELS
    METADATA
        "wms_title"    "WMS qqqq"   
    END
    VALIDATION
        "provider" "[a-z]+"
    END
    TYPE RASTER
    STATUS ON
    DATA '/xxx/xxx/xxx/%provider%/%spaceresolution%/%timeresolution%/%year%/%month%/%day%/%name%.tif'
    PROJECTION
      "init=epsg:3857"
    END
    PROCESSING "RESAMPLE=NEAREST"
    CLASSITEM "[pixel]"
    CLASS
      EXPRESSION ([pixel] = -2)
      STYLE
        COLOR 227 26 28
      END
    END
    CLASS
      EXPRESSION ([pixel] = -1)
      STYLE
        COLOR 231 245 54
      END
    END
    CLASS
      EXPRESSION ([pixel] = 0)
      STYLE
        COLOR 221 221 221
      END
    END
    CLASS
      EXPRESSION ([pixel] = 1)
      STYLE
        COLOR 0 245 0
      END
    END
    CLASS
      EXPRESSION ([pixel] = 2)
      STYLE
        COLOR 26 150 65
      END
    END
  END
END
```

I also tried to define colours based on ranges:

```
EXPRESSION ([pixel] >= 1 AND [pixel] < 2)
…
```

It didn't work.

Any ideas what might be wrong?

EDIT:

I found out the tif was produced by GrADS software

```
gdalinfo T2m-60_perc_2018_231.tif

…
Metadata:
  TIFFTAG_SOFTWARE=GrADS version 2.0.a7.1
  TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION=0.018242123
  TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION=0.02681388
  TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT=2 (pixels/inch)
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
…
```

And this might be the cause as I also found [this question](https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/mapserver-users/2014-April/076288.html), unfortunately left unanswered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Managed to solve this on my own. The problem was in the well known fact that a float is never an exact number. So 2 float is actually something like 2.9897689 or 2.000121101 and map server didn't like the fact that I wanted to display the map using whole number.
Using:

```
EXPRESSION ([pixel] >= 1 AND [pixel] < 2)
```

partially addressed the issue but stull cut odd values just above 2. So I then used:

```
EXPRESSION ([pixel] >= 1.5 AND [pixel] < 2.5)
```

to capture all of the float values around 2.